# Decals shrinkwrap bake black for alpha?

Tags: materials, transparency, baking

yo guys i have a problem , i used some decals and shrinkwrap on a object , join all of them and baked to low poly object , but the alpha is baking black , can you guys help me , and sorry for my bad english

[image]

Comment: What's your bake settings?

Comment: Not that this is relevant for your problem, but why do you invert the _Alpha_ output with a _Color Ramp_ instead of simply switching the shader inputs for _Diffuse BSDF_ and _Transparent BSDF_?

Comment: yes my bad but it's same result :)

Comment: my bake settings , extrusion .1 , selected to active , and difuse only color not direct and inderect lights

Comment: question is did you ever tried to bake some decals . .???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why that didn't work: You are basically baking objects overlapped like floaters, and while floaters are a thing and work well, they will override what is below. In the case of a decal with transparency, when baking everything to ONE place in the texture, that transparency of the decal will override what was below (the colour) with "transparent" (alpha) because a pixel cannot have color and be transparent at the same time, hence looking "black" in the baked texture while it'll actually look transparent if you turn on the alpha clip.

How to make it work? You basically have two ways:

1. Leave the decals where they are, and treat them as a different object from the same model. Here you have to make a copy of the decals as a low poly target (properly unwrapped) and can either pack everyting in one UV space and one set of textures or have a separate set of textures for the decals (if for example you want to have higher quixel density for the text). If you make a separate texture you can use it as a detail map.
2. On the other hand you can do away with the decals and instead create a second UV layout in the high poly base object. In this case you need to make an atlas for the decals (an image that contains all decals) and then include it on the base object's material unwrapping the different sections of the mesh where you want the decals. This time around is more difficult because instead of projecting the decal with shrinkwrap you have to fiddle with the UV's, so it's not easy if you want to relocate them later (you have to redo everything). For this you have to use the UV node to condition the UV atlas image to the second UV.

Pro & Cons:

Placement: Option2 is more difficult to place and it kind of stays on place while option 1 allows to move around the decals to easyly relocate them.

Texel density: Option 2 gives a more traditional low poly approach and will be the most "efficient" in terms of texel density in that the decals and background will occupy the same space in texture, though Option 1 allows for different texel densities between base object and decals (being able to have readable text w/out the need for a huge texture, though this becomes usefull only in certain objects like vehicles or structures where the scale between the base object and the text or small details differs greatly)

Simplicity: More than Option 1 or 2 is, having everything baked in one set of textures is probably the "simpler" traditional low poly approach. Leaving decals as separate objects with separate sets of textures/atlases/trim sheets is a more advanced mid poly technique and well used is very powerful but involves solving problems like where to include the second set of textures (like a detail map or part of a multiple texture UDim setup) and also having the decals not casting shadows or reflections over the base object. One thing (EDIT:I almost forgot is that for option 1, projecting directly in the High poly UV's you'll have to work with the unsmoothed version to avoid stretching and that can cause for your model to skyrocket in weight -and resources needed to run it- depending on how much subdivided it is, since it's easier for blender to emulate the subdivision than to actually work with more geometry.)

Hope this helps and if you have any doubt don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: thanks dude really nice and detailled answer , it been a while since a i posted , i just baked it without the "floaters" or "decals"(don't know how to call it) and added them in krita(it's photoshop for poors hahaha); and i think the easier way( not the best for sure because it lower the quality when u do it) is just to use stencil feature in blender :) but thanks dude really nice advices there , i see that you are a pro :)